# How to refresh data on console but keep the progress bar run fluently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, progress-bar, tqdm

Is it possible do it?
I tried

```
from tqdm import tqdm
total = 0
for q in tqdm(range(100,0,-1)):
    total=total+1
    sys.stdout.write("\b"+str(total))
    time.sleep(1)
```

and

```
from tqdm import tqdm
total = 0
for q in tqdm(range(100,0,-1)):
    total=total+1
    clear()
    print(str(total))
    sleep(0.3)
```

But all is broken result. Please if there is any way to do it, teach me. Thank you.

Comment: The `"\b"`/`"\r"` trick only works in certain consoles in certain modes. What exactly is broken?

Comment: Seems like someone else is also experiencing the issue: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/724 I just tried your code with `tqdm.write(str(total))`. The git issue description seems to suggest that using anaconda will give you what you're looking for.